# Execute a batch file in a synlock to wait for the internal process of it to finish in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I need to execute a batch file in a module in `vb.Net`, but the problem is I execute the same and if finish or not the program execute the next step.

If execute the next step my process is broken because is a create a text file and the next step is upload in data base `mysql`.

I try execute in a synlcok and dont have any diference, how use the synlock to finalize the execution of the batch file.

My code is:

```
Dim myLock As Object

synlock myLock
    Dim pProces As Process = Process.Start(psi)
End synlock

delay(350)
```

PS: delay is a rename to thread wait, the process continue in the wait but I need know when it finishes executing the batch file.

Comment: Is there a reason why [Wait​For​Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit_System_Int32_) can't be used?

Comment: Why execute a batch file at all? Batch is a far more error prone way of doing a task. Certainly it can't be so complicated that it could not easily be done in code.

Comment: I use the a batch file beacauese is file to execute a pentaho and this script change the information extracted, how is the unhandedExcepSean I have never used it

Comment: The_Lotus, sory but WaitForExit I have never used it, 
you have an example of use so that you can use in my code, I would be very grateful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your problem exactly, you want to wait for the batch file to finish executing before going to the next part of your code.

You can use `process.HasExited` to wait for the process to finish.

```
Dim pProces As Process = Process.Start(psi)

While Not pProces.HasExited
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents ' if this is a windows form or console app
End While

If pProces.ExitCode = 0 Then
    ' Continue your next step here
Else
    ' Error occured while running the batch file 
End If
```

**OR**

You can use [Process.Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.

Comment: This is OK (I guess) as a toy program, but it's very poorly behaved for more serious use (reason for downvote).  It will peg the processor as it busy-waits.  I'd recommend to use `WaitForExit` (also suggested by the_lotus) which should use the built-in Windows wait primitives to avoid busy-waiting.  (In general `DoEvents` is considered harmful in a modern VB program.)

Comment: Well, the example I gave above is from a much larger isolated process thread. Thread blocking is not a problem. The DoEvents was not there originally.